# why can't i use insert_batch like this in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i am using codeigniter , i use the `insert_batch` function . i have a table structure like this

[image]

an i am using an array like this to `insert_batch` function

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ProfileID] => 5
            [ActivityTypeID] => 4
            [ActivityTitle] => bbggg
            [ActivityLink] => http://localhost/elephanti2/home/user/action/settings/user/profilesettings
            [IsActive] => 1
            [CreatedOn] => 1331532905
            [CreatedBy] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ActivityImage] => 
            [ActivityTitle] => kkkkkkkk
            [ActivityFromDate] => 1330642800
            [ActivityToDate] => 1331852400
            [ActivityDescription] => kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
            [ActivityLink] => 
            [CreatedOn] => 1331532905
            [CreatedBy] => 5
            [ProfileID] => 5
            [ActivityTypeID] => 1
        )

)
```

error is given

[image]

why this happens

**can't i use arrays with different keys ???????**

please help.............. thanks in advance

Comment: @linuxeasy simple code $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);

Comment: check your array it is not in a way you specified since the column names are empty in sql statment and the second value contains an array ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`insert_batch` translations into a SQL query that uses the `VALUES` form of `INSERT`. This requires every item being inserted to specify the same fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue after change the line of code in the file "system\database\DB_query_builder.php"

Replace the code in the the file DB_query_builder.php, Path : "system\database\DB_query_builder.php"

```
protected function _insert_batch($table, $keys, $values)
{
return 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES '.implode(', ', $values);
}
```

**By below code**

```
protected function _insert_batch($table, $keys, $values)
{
if(is_array($values))
{
$values = implode(',',$values);
}
return 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES '.implode(', ', $values);
}
```

I have resolved my issue by this way. hope, same will work for you.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your frameworks core classes but rather extend them and replace the method in your class. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class